# Algorithm for tracking values through time

Tags: algorithm, permutation, matching, trend

There is likely a known algorithm for doing this, but I wasn't able to find it using my Google skills, so I will try to describe what I have to do and what I did so far.

I have a source of characteristic values of a system which I would like to plot as a trend. The values are being returned from an algorithm in real time, and each value has a set of properties (magnitude, phase, quality).

However, these values can appear and disappear in time, and I can also get some intermittent values which I will disregard if they don't repeat during a longer period (several samples).

For example, I might be getting these values:

```
Time     (Mag, Phase, Quality)
t = 1    (10.10, 0.90, 0.90);  (17.00, 0.02, 0,12)
t = 2    (10.15, 0.91, 0.89);  (17.10, 0.12, 0,12)
t = 3    (17.10, 0.12, 0,12)
t = 4    (10.25, 0.91, 0.89);  (17.12, 0.12, 0,12)
t = 5    ( 6.15, 0.41, 0.39);  (10.35, 0.91, 0.89);  (17.12, 0.12, 0,12)
t = 6    (10.20, 0.90, 0.85);  (17.02, 0.13, 0,11)
t = 7    ( 9.20, 0.90, 0.85);  (11.20, 0.90, 0.85);  (17.02, 0.13, 0,11)
t = 8    ( 9.80, 0.90, 0.85);  (11.80, 0.90, 0.85);  (17.02, 0.13, 0,11)
```

I'd like to track these sets of values through time according to the similarity with previous values. I.e. in the example above, I have two main trends (`Mag 10` and `Mag 17`), with several specific situations:

1. moments where I will shortly lose one of the values (`Mag 10` is lost in `t = 3`),
2. moments where I shortly get a new temporary/invalid reading (`Mag 6` in `t = 5`) for a single sample,
3. moments where it's not completely clear which set corresponds to the previous sample (`Mag 9.2` and `Mag 11.2` could both be a continuation of `Mag 10.2` from the previous sample, and in `t = 8` it becomes apparent that there are now two different sets (`Mag 9.8` and `Mag 11.8`).

If I just grouped the values as they arrive from the system, I would not get their correct trends, i.e. without tracking, the magnitudes would appear like this:

[image: Naive trend of received values]

However, properly matching these values against old magnitude should result in this trend:

[image: Actual tracked magnitudes]

I've written an algorithm which tracks the values through time by effectively trying all permutations of sets against the previous "active" sets. It calculates the differences between all new values and the previous known values, which is basically a `N^2` algorithm, and then checks all permutations to find the smallest total distance (something like `N!` complexity):

```
for each X in new_sets
     for each Y in existing_sets
           distance(X, Y) = calculate_distance(X, Y);

for each P in permutations(new_sets)
     total_distance = sum(distance(X, Y)) for all (X, Y) in permutation

permutation P with min total_distance is the best match
```

As I go through time, I also remove measurements from `existing_sets` if they are not matched within several samples.

This works reasonable fine, as long as I don't have too many values, but the time complexity becomes problematic after I begin tracking more than 10 items. It also feels like reinventing the wheel.

Is there a known/better (in terms of time complexity) algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Maybe a [sliding window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm#Sliding_window_model) model?

Answer (score 0):

Without constraints on the behaviour of the sources, there is obviously no solution. If we may say that the magnitudes from different sources are reasonably separated, and changes are reasonably small, the solution is to keep the trends in the sorted order. Then binary search them to find the trend closest to the new reading.